# Is there a colorful term for an uninvited guest?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, word-request

Is there a colorful Latin term for an uninvited guest?
Of course I can say something like *conviva non invitatus*, but I wonder if there is something less boring, akin to the English "gatecrasher" or the Finnish "kuokkavieras" (lit. "mattock guest").
Does anyone know a suitable phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just now stumbled upon an idiomatic word for an uninvited guest: ***umbra*** (see [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=umbra&la=la#lexicon), definition at I.B.3)

In a description of a disastrous dinner party, Horace mentions:

> *quos Maecenas adduxerat **umbras***
>
> the **uninvited guests** that Maecenas had brought with him

Horace, *Satires*, 2.8.22

And in a dinner party invitation to Torquatus, Horace promises that:

> *locus est et pluribus **umbris***
>
> there is room too for several **uninvited guests**

Horace, *Epistles*, 1.5.28

Answer (score 3):

I was sure that Catullus or Martial would be full of gate crashers - it seems like something they would love to mock.  Alas, I couldn't find any!

I did find the following and it’s interesting to see that Macrobius’ use of *[inruere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=inruere&la=la#lexicon)* (“to fall with violence, rush down; to fall down”) in the following almost parallels the English sense of *crashing* a party:

> *tunc ille: ‘supervenire fabulis **non evocatos** haud equidem turpe
>   existimatur, verum sponte **inruere** in convivium aliis praeparatum … ’*
>
> then he said: ‘For my part I think there’s nothing disgraceful for the
>   **uninvited** to add to a conversation [already underway], but to
>   willingly **crash** a party prepared for others [that’s not acceptable] …’

Macrobius, *Saturnalia*, 1.10

Note too his use of *non evocatus* for *not invited*, rather than *non invitatus*.  I realise Macrobius is quite late but see also *[invocatus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=invocatus&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=invocatus2-contents)* to mean *uninvited*, which is attested much earlier than Macrobius.  Not a very interesting or colourful term, I admit.

Perhaps *[asymbolus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=asumbolum&la=la#lexicon)* would work, defined as not contributing anything to a party or meal.  It’s from the Greek ἀσύμβολος, itself a reference to the custom of [συμβολή](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sumbolh%2F&la=greek&can=sumbolh%2F0&prior=on#lexicon), “contributions made to provide a common meal; … contribution, subscription to the expenses of a festival, etc.”  This at least captures the free-loading character of the gate crasher if not explicitly referencing their lack of an invitation (because I guess someone could legitimately be at a dinner party yet still arrive empty-handed).

Comment: I had to unaccept this one, since there was a more colorful suggestion in another answer. I hope you don't mind. ;)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Not at all ;)